# Beginners first try at coding rock, paper.. game. Keeps returning 'paper wins'

Tags: javascript

I keep getting 'paper wins' when I enter 'rock' as my choice.

```
function game() {
  pChoice = prompt('What is your play?');
  cChoice = ['rock','paper','scissor'];
  
  let compChoice = [Math.floor(Math.random() * cChoice.length)];
  console.log(compChoice);

  function compare(pChoice, compChoice) {
    if (pChoice === compChoice) {
      alert( "It's a tie" );
    }

    if (pChoice === 'rock') {
      if (compChoice === 'scissor') {
        return 'rock wins';
      } else {
        return 'paper wins';    
      }
    }
    else if (pChoice === 'paper') {
      if (compChoice === 'rock') {
        return 'paper wins';
      } else {
        return 'scissor wins';
      }
    }
    else if (pChoice === 'scissor') {
      if (compChoice === 'paper') {
        return 'scissor wins';
      } else {
        return 'rock wins';
      }
    }
  }

  var result = compare(pChoice, compChoice);
  console.log(compare(pChoice, compChoice));
}

game();
```

Comment: `compChoice` is not a string so that `if` statement will never be true. I guess you want `cChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * cChoice.length)]` ?

Comment: Hint: Where is `cChoice` used? There's no code that does `cChoice[...]` to look up one of the three strings.

Comment: thanks. 
When I 

let compChoice = [Math.floor(Math.random() * cChoice.length)];

Comment: doesn't that let compChoice equal the random array choice from cChoice?

Comment: let compChoice=cChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * cChoice.length)]

Comment: just tried it out. Really appreciate it. Next time I'll try it out before responding back with a question

Answer (score 2):

You never assign cChoice to a value, instead you are assigning it to an array with a number in it.

For example:

```
// Assigning to [number]
let compChoice = [Math.floor(Math.random() * cChoice.length)];
// Assigning to string inside of array cChoice
let compChoice = cChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * cChoice.length)];
```

Comment: There are quite a few flaws... but this is probably the biggest